# Python/Tkinter Frontend Frame

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, responsive-design, desktop-application

[When opened normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiGQ3.png)
[Fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Kj4.png)

i'm working on my first ever project, and i'm using python/tkinter. i've come  up with this design(above) but i can't make it responsive.

i want the bottom section to stay the same but i want to extend the top part through the bottom.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(topFrame)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(topFrame)
listbox.pack(fill=BOTH)

for i in range(100):
    listbox.insert(END, i)
```

#attaching list and scroll

```
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

#bottom frame

bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
```

#bottom laft frame

```
b_leftFrame = Frame(bottomFrame)
b_leftFrame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)
```

#defining label

```
label1 = Label(b_leftFrame, text="Title")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)

label2 = Label(b_leftFrame, text="Author")
label2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E)

label3 = Label(b_leftFrame, text="Publisher")
label3.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=E)

label4 = Label(b_leftFrame, text="Year")
label4.grid(row=0, column=6, sticky=E)

label5 = Label(b_leftFrame, text="Translator")
label5.grid(row=0, column=8, sticky=E)
```

#defining labels

```
title_text =StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(b_leftFrame, textvariable=title_text)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)

author_text =StringVar()
entry2 = Entry(b_leftFrame, textvariable=author_text)
entry2.grid(row=0, column=3)

publisher_text =StringVar()
entry3 = Entry(b_leftFrame, textvariable=publisher_text)
entry3.grid(row=0, column=5)

year_text =StringVar()
entry4 = Entry(b_leftFrame, textvariable=year_text)
entry4.grid(row=0, column=7)

translator_text =StringVar()
entry4 = Entry(b_leftFrame, textvariable=translator_text)
entry4.grid(row=0, column=9)
```

#bottom right

```
b_rightFrame = Frame(bottomFrame)
b_rightFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

#buttons

```
b1=Button(b_rightFrame, text="View All", width=12)
b1.grid(row=2, column=3)

b1=Button(b_rightFrame, text="Search Entry", width=12)
b1.grid(row=3, column=3)

b1=Button(b_rightFrame, text="Add Entry", width=12)
b1.grid(row=4, column=3)

b1=Button(b_rightFrame, text="Update selected", width=12)
b1.grid(row=5, column=3)

b1=Button(b_rightFrame, text="Delete selected", width=12)
b1.grid(row=6, column=3)

b1=Button(b_rightFrame, text="Close", width=12)
b1.grid(row=7, column=3)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is `afaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the topFrame widget, which contains the Listbox, is not taking all the available space.

Try replacing your:

```
topFrame.pack(fill=BOTH)
```

with:

```
topFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

This will make the topFrame expand once you maximize the window.

Also, in order to make the listbox expand as well, replace your

```
listbox.pack(fill=BOTH)
```

with:

```
listbox.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

Comment: that works, many thanks. with only the changes that you suggested, how can i center the b_leftFrame, which sticks to left when fullscreen. how can i center it?

Comment: Do you want it to expand in size or just center and keep the same width?

Comment: just center while keeping the same width

Comment: Add a `b_leftFrame.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)` after each of your label and entry .grid, by replacing column with the real one